# Android Market Place App Upload Error

Tags: android

I'm having trouble uploading an app to the market place.  When the app is uploaded an error is displayed stating that the apk is not valid.  But no reason is given.

I believe I have everything correct in the manifest file and I went through the process in eclipse to obtain a valid key (Export-Create a new key store- etc.)

The manifest file is posted below.  Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.totaltodolist2"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
      <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"></uses-sdk>


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>

<application android:icon="@drawable/newglobe" android:label="Total to Do List">

    <activity android:name="AddNewContact"></activity>
    <activity android:name="contactLookUp"></activity>
    <activity android:name="EditContact"></activity>
    <activity android:name="SevenListEntryActivity">

    </activity>       
    <activity android:name="ItemOptions"></activity>    
    <activity android:name="MakeCallActivity" android:noHistory="true"></activity>
    <activity android:name="PickDateActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="SevenListActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="SevenListDisplayActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="TextActivity" android:noHistory="true"></activity>
    <activity android:name="WebActivity" android:noHistory="true"></activity>
    <activity android:name="Begin"> </activity>
    <activity android:name="StartPage">       
     <intent-filter>        
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>            

    </activity>
    <activity android:name="SettingsActivity"></activity>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" /> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" /> 

  </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is your whole manifest, you are missing some key elements.

For example:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.mypackage.name.appname"
      android:versionName="@string/version" android:versionCode="15">
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="7" android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
        <activity spam here>
    </application>
  <define permissions here>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I've tried to make the changes you suggested but still get the error. It goes like this: browse-select my apk file. message is displayed: Draft application .apk file click the 'publish' button to publish draft apk file-I then select publish and get the error: apk is not valid. I try to upload it again and get: You have another application on Market with the same package name (name of the package). Go to that other application, and click upgrade. However, application is not listed on my account to be upgraded.